# headimage.png:1 GET http://localhost:3000/assets/images/headimage.png 404 (Not Found)

Tags: reactjs, image, http-status-code-404, vite

When i try to acccess an image from a assets/images/headimage.png it is not rendering in page
and showing error not found.I tried so many ways and i can't resolve my problem. Any one please explain the problem for this.

[image: Here is the image of folder structure and code]

Comment: Why not using the `public` folder? Otherwise, use the `src={require("./path")}`

Answer (score 1):

In React you need to import the asset first: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/. You cannot reference it directly in the code.

```
import headImage from "../assets/images/headimage.png"

...

<img src={headImage} />
```